# Разница между методом по умолчанию в интерфейсе и обычным методом в классе

Tags: java, классы, методы, интерфейс, java-8

Чем отличаются между собой `метод по умолчанию`, объявленный в интерфейсе с модификатором `default` и обычный метод, объявленный в обычном классе?

(*update*) [**Читаю**](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/31953201/)

> Метод по умолчанию представляет собой метод, который объявлен в интерфейсе с модификатором `default`; его тело всегда представлено блоком. Он предоставляет реализацию по умолчанию для любого класса, который реализует интерфейс без перекрытия метода. **Методы по умолчанию отличны от конкретных методов, которые объявляются в классах.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

default метод не может обращаться к состоянию объекта (полям объекта), так как никакого объекта нет, но может вызвать другие методы и обращаться к статическим данным (константам).

default метод позволяет избежать необходимости изменить все классы, которые реализуют этот интерфейс.

В классе, реализующим интерфейс с default методами, вы можете их переопределить.

```
interface I1 {
    // это public static final int i = 0;
    // но в описании интерфейса public static final можно опустить
    int i = 0;
    default void m1() {
        System.out.println("I1 m1 i = " + i);
        m2();
    }

    void m2();
}
```

Без `default` этот класс бы не скомпилировался:

```
public class C1 implements I1 {
    @Override
    public void m2() {
        System.out.println("C1 m2");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new C1().m1();
        new C1().m2();
    }
}
```

Вывод будет следующим:

```
I1 m1 i = 0
C1 m2
C1 m2
```

Comment: многие начинающие забывают, что у интерфейса нет доступа к state (состоянию). поэтому я это и упомянул. в данном случае - это фигура речи.

Answer (score 3):

Одно из различий заключается в том, что все методы (в т.ч. и `default`) в интерфейсе неявно объявлены как `public` и поменять этот модификатор доступа не получится, а в обычном методе в классе Вы можете сами устанавливать различные модификаторы доступа.

**UPD:**

> Метод по умолчанию представляет собой метод, который объявлен в интерфейсе с модификатором default; его тело всегда представлено блоком. Он предоставляет реализацию по умолчанию для любого класса, который реализует интерфейс без перекрытия метода. **Методы по умолчанию отличны от конкретных методов, которые объявляются в классах.**

Вы несколько неправильно поняли это предложение. Здесь имелось ввиду то, что если класс реализует интерфейс, который содержит `default`-метод, то при переопределении в классе этого метода, метод из класса перекроет `default`-реализацию.

Попробуйте сделать акцент на выделенном тексте, тогда поймете о чем я:

> Он предоставляет реализацию по умолчанию для любого класса, который реализует интерфейс **без перекрытия метода**. Методы по умолчанию **отличны от конкретных методов**, которые объявляются в классах.

К тому же, если бы здесь имелись ввиду какие-то **принципиальные** различия, то они здесь же были бы указаны, так как в этом пункте из главы про интерфейсы рассказывается непосредственно про `default`-методы.

Comment: `@post_zeew: я предельно внимательно раздумываю ваше уточнение, спасибо

Comment: вы правы, видимо я поспешил выдумывать различия. Мне как-то пересформулировать вопрос?

Comment: @TimurVI, Я думаю лучше оставить как есть. Так как как минимум одно различие я описал. Хотя это различие применимо ко всем методам интерфейса, а не только к `default`.

Comment: А второе различие привел @Mikhail Vaysman (в первом предложении ответа), хотя оно тоже справедливо для всех методов интерфейса.