# В чём разница между İnterface и Abstract класс

Tags: java, классы, интерфейс

Раньше `interface` не имел реализации и нам приходилось реализовывать абстрактные классы. Но сейчас, а конкретно, начиная с 'Java8', interface может иметь реализацию. Зачем так поступили? В чём здесь выигрыш? Какие преимущества дает интерфейс, имеющий реализацию? И главное, в чем тогда смысл использования абстрактных классов, если интерфейс может содержать реализацию методов?

Comment: @elik например у вас есть листенер на 20 полей и всех **достало** писать 20 пустых методов (когда нужен 1 только). А делать классом нельзя - и семантика не та и конфликты наследования. А пустая реализация - то что надо.

Comment: см. также : https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/621959

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отличия абстрактного класса от интерфейса (abstract class and interface)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/235352/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%b0-abstract-class-and-interface)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Интерфейс описывает только поведение (методы) и не может иметь состояние (поля), абстрактный класс - может.

В случае с `default`-методами, поведение может быть не только описано, но и реализовано. Однако по-прежнему без доступа к состоянию.

В Java 8 `default`-методы были добавлены во многом ради Stream API. Это позволило добавить методы `spliterator()` и `stream()` всем коллекциям, которые были написаны до появления Stream API, не затрагивая их реализации:

```
public interface Iterable<T>
    // ...

    default Spliterator<T> spliterator() {
        return Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator(), 0);
    }
}

public interface Collection<E> extends Iterable<E> {
    // ...

    @Override
    default Spliterator<E> spliterator() {
        return Spliterators.spliterator(this, 0);
    }

    default Stream<E> stream() {
        return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator(), false);
    }
}
```

Как видите, **default**-методы тут ведут себя как миксины, оборачивающие некоторую стороннюю реализацию (`Spliterators`, `StreamSupport`) и превращающую ее в честные методы коллекций.

---

Пример из жизни. Есть интерфейс доступа к данным, который может иметь разные реализации:

```
public interface Repository {
    Foo getFooWithTimeout(int id, int timeout);
    // ...
}
```

И хочется иметь его сокращенную версию какого-то метода со значениями параметров по-умолчанию. Тогда достаточно просто обернуть существующий метод default-методом:

```
public interface Repository {
    Foo getFooWithTimeout(int id, int timeout);

    default Foo getFoo(int id) {
        return getFooWithTimeout(id, 0);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Мы расширили контракт всех реализаций интерфейса `Repository` новым методом, при этом <strike>никто не пострадал</strike> нам не пришлось вторгаться в реализации.

Comment: Хотел бы добавить, что default-методы  - это, еще и шаг в сторону множественного наследования. В Java, класс не может наследоваться от нескольких абстрактных классов, а реализовывать несколько интерфейсов - может.